# RESTful Rails & encapsulating behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, encapsulation, behavior

Background - I have a model, say Door, that has a state of open or closed. I encapsulate the behaviour of opening the door in a method #open on each instance (And I also have a #close equivalent).

But what's the best way to expose this in a RESTful way? What should my route be?

It is an UPDATE to Door instance, but what should I UPDATE with?

Cheers,
Gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one best way that everybody would agree on.

Some people would add two custom actions `open` and `close` to their controllers, which would then call the respective methods on the `Door` model.

Other people would use the `update` controller method to change whatever attribute the door uses to store its open/closed state. e.g. a boolean field `closed`. They might also argue that you should not have dedicated `open` and `close` methods besides the `closed` attribute, and that you implement with validations and callbacks whatever `open`/`close` used to encapsulate.

My recommendation is not to worry too much about RESTfulness and always choose the most practical way.

Comment: Thanks henning-koch, there is a strange comfort in knowing there is no best way! Probably because I expected it!